# Where should onActivityResult be handled, dialog fragment, fragment, or activity?

Tags: android, fragment, android-camera-intent, dialogfragment, onactivityresult

In my android app, I have a fragment where the user can add a picture, either from gallery or from camera. I've created an alert dialog and placed it in a DialogFragment. When the user chooses an option, I call startActivityForResult. My question is, where should ideally this result be handled? (i.e. where should i place onActivityResult?) In the DialogFragment class, the host fragment, or the host activity? Does it matter?

Comment: I use the ActivityForResult() in my activity that hosts the DialogFragments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onActivityResult()` will be invoked first on the Activity. After that it will be reached out to the Fragments, if you call `super.onActivityResult()` in your Activity.

This is because of the modular design of Fragments. If a result comes in, the Activity handles it and the unhandled results, if any, can be reached out to the Fragments.

To answer your question: Decide where it makes sense to handle the results in respect of your app design / code. If you handle it in the Fragment and send the results back to the Activity through a callback f.e., you can handle it directly in the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You must write `onActivityResult()` in your `HostActivity.Java` as follows:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does matter; It is the activity that receives the result, based on that result you decide what actions to take further, notify your fragments or whatever is that you need.