# Android Dialog Fragments and onActivityResult

Tags: android, onactivityresult, dialogfragment

I have created an application that presents the user with a dialog fragment with two options: `Yes` and `No`.

Should the user select 'Yes', the app will call a Zxing barscan application that is installed on the device, and return the result.

Now, I have a proof of concept for this working. However this proof of concept uses a simple Activity. Therefore I can achieve this Barscan result using activity, not with Dialog Fragment.

The code used in the proof of concept is as follows:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    //retrieve scan result
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (scanningResult != null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();      
        String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
        contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
        }
    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }   
}
```

This code will not work with a dialog fragment. I have been searching and came upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10905312) question.

However it will not integrate, as I cannot access the requestCode, resultCode, or intent required, and am quite confused as to how to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fragment should launch activity by `startActivityForResult` not `getActivity().startActivityForResult`

In your activity in `onActivityResult` call `super.onActivityResult` and in your fragment on `onActivityResult` you can put your code which you have posted here.

More info why:

- [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment)
- [Where should onActivityResult be handled, dialog fragment, fragment, or activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518826/where-should-onactivityresult-be-handled-dialog-fragment-fragment-or-activity)

Comment: Thank Than. So I understand correctly, I should add onActivityResult() to the activity calling the fragment. It is in this activity that I can retrieve the results from the barscan application?

Comment: Well it depends where do you want to handle your response. If inside fragment, do what i wrote up here, If inside activity call it by getActivity().startActivityForResult and handle it in activity.