# Android onActivityResult in dialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

There is a DialogFragment (`SettingsBackImageDialog`) opens by click on button in Fragment (`TrainerSettings`) in MainActivity. In `SettingsBackImageDialog` are some buttons, one of them is for take picture and set it for Imageview (`trainersettingsmainicon`) in Fragment.

I open `SettingsBackImageDialog` in `TrainerSettings` by:

```
    public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
            view.findViewById(R.id.trainersettingsbackgroundbtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showEditbackImageDialog();
                }
            });
        }

private void showEditbackImageDialog() {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        SettingsBackImageDialog settingsBackImageDialog = SettingsBackImageDialog.newInstance("Wybierz pierwszy kolor");
        settingsBackImageDialog.show(fm, "SettingsBackImageDialog");
    }
```

My code from `SettingsBackImageDialog` is:

```
    public class SettingsBackImageDialog extends DialogFragment {

        int REQUESTCODE=1;

        public SettingsBackImageDialog() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.settingsbackgroundimgdialog, container);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            view.findViewById(R.id.takephotobtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(i, REQUESTCODE);
                }
            });

            String title = getArguments().getString("txt", "txt");
            getDialog().setTitle(title);
            getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        }


        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "before", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(requestCode==REQUESTCODE & resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)bundle.get("data");
                ImageView img = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.trainersettingsmainicon);
                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

In `MainActivity`:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.MainContainer);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "im here", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Application opens camera, I can take piture and "accept" it but nothing else happend. Probably application never uses onActivityResult method (I try to write some message in this method but nothing happend).

In AndroidMonitor:

```
05-09 02:43:50.299 9709-10068/com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8115000 but found 5089070
05-09 02:43:50.339 9709-9709/com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

I use nox app to emulate android phone.

What should I do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

The selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699207/android-dialog-fragments-and-onactivityresult?rq=1) addresses your problem exactly. You also need to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518826/where-should-onactivityresult-be-handled-dialog-fragment-fragment-or-activity) which addresses the question of where the `onActivityResult` should be handled.
My suggestion is that you change your code as follows:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
   view.findViewById(R.id.takephotobtn).setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //changed getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, REQUESTCODE); to:
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUESTCODE);
            }
        });

        String title = getArguments().getString("txt", "txt");
        getDialog().setTitle(title);
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    }
```

`onActivityResult()` will be invoked first on the `Activity`. After that it will be reached out to the `Fragments`, if you call `super.onActivityResult()` in your Activity. So you need to add the `onActivityResult` callback in your `Activity` - so that the one in your `Fragment` can be invoked.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Once that is done, the `onActivityResult` on your Fragment will be invoked and your code will be executed as you expect.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==REQUESTCODE & resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)bundle.get("data");
        ImageView img = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.trainersettingsmainicon);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

You need to look at these two closely related

Comment: So I should use super.super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); in `SettingsBackImageDialog` and onActivityResult with if() in MainActivity?

Comment: NO, the other way around, you should call `super.onActivityResult...` in your MainActivity's onActivityResult - then the code you already have in your Fragment's onActivityResult is good - no need to change/move it.

Comment: It doesn't work (onActivityResult in `SettingsBackImageDialog` is still not used). Is that any problem that this is DialogFragment, not just Fragment?

Comment: Can you please post the latest version of your code - this will help me see which changes you have made or if you made all the necessary changes. For instance, did you call `startActivityForResult(i, REQUESTCODE);` in your Fragment - or did you call `getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, REQUESTCODE);`.

Comment: Can you change the MainActivity onActivityResults and explicitly call the onActivityResult on your Fragment like this:                                    `Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your-fragment-id);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

Comment: Do you mean `SettingsBackImageDialog` or `TrainerSettings`

Comment: Which one has the code for `onActivityResult`? That's the one.

Comment: Should I use id like [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363072/android-set-fragment-id) (FrameLayout id from mainActivity xml?)

Comment: Yes, please try that and let;s see if it works. Also, please add Log statement in your MainActivity's onActivityResults - just to see if it gets invoked at least.

Comment: I put in my post what actually is in MainActivity. If i click on buton there is toast "im here" but the picture doesn't change.

Comment: This is a good sign - now in your Fragment's onActivityResult - can you please add a log statement there as well - before the IF block - just so we are sure that this one too gets called -if this is the case, then perhaps we should review the IF block.

Comment: This is strange. Ok, by the way, your `MainActivity` does it extend `FragmentActivity`? Also, the code that handles your onActivityResult does not see to "depend" on the Fragment, so perhaps you should move the code to the MainActivity's onActivityResult.

Comment: `MainActivity` does't, `TrainerSettings` extends `Fragment` and `SettingsBackImageDialog` extends `DialogFragment`. So remove onActivityResult() from `SettingsBackImageDialog` and put this code in onActivityResult() in `MainActivity`?

Comment: You can try first to extend `FragmentActivity` in your MainActivity - if this does not work, you can then try and move the onActivityResult code - but in this case you change `ImageView img = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.trainersettingsmainicon);` to this:  `ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trainersettingsmainicon);`

Comment: I use extends` AppCompatActivity` in `MainActivity`. If I put code from onActivityResult (in `SettingsBackImageDialog`) to the same method in `MainActivity` . There is problem in `if()`, I have `requestCode==REQUESTCODE`, `REQUESTCODE` is 1 but `requestCode` is not const: for example is '131073' or '196609' or...